# How to prove $1 \leq \int_0^{1}\frac{e^x}{1-\sin(x)}dx \leq 8e$?

Tags: calculus

I need to prove that: $$1 \leq \int_0^{1}\frac{e^x}{1-\sin(x)}dx \leq 8e$$
To be honest I don't even know where to begin! Can you give me some directions?

Answer (score 0):

What's the minimum and maximum of $e^x$ on $[0,1]$?  Hint:  $e^x$ is increasing on $[0,1]$.

What's the minimum and maximum of $1- \sin x$ on $[0,1]$?  Hint: $1-\sin x$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$.

How can you use these pieces of info to put bounds on the integral?

Answer (score 0):

On this interval, we have:
$$
0=\sin0\leq\sin x\leq\sin1
$$
THus:
$$
e^x=\frac{e^x}{1-\sin0}\leq \frac{e^x}{1-\sin x}\leq\frac{e^x}{1-\sin1}
$$
THus:
$$
\int_0^1\frac{e^x\mathrm{d}x}{1}=e-1
\leq\int_0^1\frac{e^x\mathrm{d}x}{1-\sin x}
\leq\int_0^1\frac{e^x\mathrm{d}x}{1-\sin 1}=\frac{e-1}{1-\sin1}
$$
Now by 
$$
\sin x\geq x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}
$$
thus:
$$
1-\sin 1\geq\frac{19}{120}>\frac{1}{7}
$$
Thus:
$$
1<1.7182<e-1<\int_0^1\frac{e^x\mathrm{d}x}{1-\sin x}<\frac{e-1}{1-\sin1}<7(e-1)<8e
$$

Comment: The inequality when comparing $\sin x$ to $x-{x^3\over6}+{x^5\over120}$ should point the other way.  (The next line, though, is OK, because you're *subtracting* $\sin 1$.)